# Надо сделать так, чтоб при вводе информации в месседж бокс она добавлялась и сохранялась в бд sql

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Вот что есть сейчас:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать это (я новичок)

Comment: Записывать в базу данных. Изучите работу с конкретной БД, с которой вы планируете работать - MySQL, Sqlite или чем там, потом пишете код открытия сеанса с БД, код, который введенную информацию преобразует в запрос к базе данных, и много другого кода... Новичок - это еще не повод, чтобы все делали за вас, да и в рамках вопроса пересказать пару толстых книг все равно не реально...

Comment: Мне просто нужен код боже... чтобы это реализовать как в обычном текст боксе. Не думаю что это так сложно

Comment: Ну, вот простенький пример с MySQL - https://habr.com/ru/post/131576/ Или с SQLite - https://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec/

Comment: Погодь, а вы знаете как решить данную проблему? Просто осталось 30 минут до защиты, и хотелось бы показать ему доделанную работу. Если вы знаете, и есть желание помочь, то можете пожалуйста написать свой дискорд, я думаю там мы решим эту проблему за 5 минут.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11519/195342